# Save data of custom billing field Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

In Woocommerce I add a custom billing field: billing_company_number. I can store the input in the admin part and on e-mails, but I can not store it in the form, so it has to be typed in over again if even if an order is placed. Unless the user creates an account.

```
function customize_billing_fields( $fields ) {

$fields['billing_company_number'] = array(

'label'     => __('KvK nummer', 'woocommerce'),
'required'  => true,
'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
'clear'     => true,
'default'   => get_user_meta('billing_company_number', true )

 );

   $fields['billing_first_name']['label'] = 'Contactpersoon Voornaam';
   $fields['billing_phone']['label'] = 'Telefoonnummer';

   $fields['billing_company']['priority'] = 0;
   $fields['billing_company_number']['priority'] = 5; 
   $fields['billing_postcode']['priority'] = 55;

return $fields;}

function me_save_extra_checkout_fields( $order, $data ){

if( isset( $data['billing_company_number'] ) ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( '_billing_company_number', sanitize_text_field( $data['billing_company_number'] ) );
} }add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'me_save_extra_checkout_fields', 10, 2 );
```